# input time mask using jquery

Tags: jquery, time, masking

I am using [meioMask](http://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask/raw/08b92c411a60ace9131de697179fda433178b8d9/jquery.meio.mask.js) – a jQuery mask plugin to put time mask in a textbox. Here is the [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/9dgYN/). It's working well. But I also need to put `hh:mm` in the textbox, to let the user know what to enter in the textbox.

How to do this.

**EDIT:** I also need to put am/pm in the mask. and I need 12 hrs time format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to set this with the plugin.

Here's a start maybe?

If you look in the code, I think you should be passing `setMask` an `options` object. It looks like `defaultValue` is a possible option.

It looks like the following should work (but it doesn't):

```
   $("#txtTime").setMask({mask: "time", defaultValue:"hh:mm"});
```

This is what I was looking at:

```
$.fn.extend({
        setMask : function(options){
            return $.mask.set(this, options);
        },
```

And

```
        // default settings for the plugin
        options : {
            attr: 'alt', // an attr to look for the mask name or the mask itself
            mask: null, // the mask to be used on the input
            type: 'fixed', // the mask of this mask
            maxLength: -1, // the maxLength of the mask
            defaultValue: '', // the default value for this input
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want it simple and clean here's a quick, but complete, demo (See: http://jsfiddle.net/bEJB2/ ) that includes a `placeholder` and a mask working together. It uses the jQuery Plugin [jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput). The JavaScript is so clean and clear

```
<div class="time-container">
     <h1> Demo of Mask for 12 Hour AM/PM Input Field w/ Place Holder </h1>

    <input class="timepicker" type="text" size="10" placeholder="hh:mm PM" />
</div>
<script>
    $.mask.definitions['H'] = "[0-1]";
    $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0-9]";
    $.mask.definitions['M'] = "[0-5]";
    $.mask.definitions['m'] = "[0-9]";
    $.mask.definitions['P'] = "[AaPp]";
    $.mask.definitions['p'] = "[Mm]";

    $(".timepicker").mask("Hh:Mm Pp");
</script>
```

I would echo what @YiJiang said about [PolyFills and Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for `placeholder` handling in non-HTML5 browsers as well.

Answer (score 3):

using jQuery Masked Input Plugin.

```
$.mask.definitions['H'] = "[0-2]";
$.mask.definitions['h'] = "[0-9]";
$.mask.definitions['M'] = "[0-5]";
$.mask.definitions['m'] = "[0-9]";
$(".timepicker").mask("Hh:Mm", {
    completed: function() {
        var currentMask = $(this).mask();
        if (isNaN(parseInt(currentMask))) {
            $(this).val("");
        } else if (parseInt(currentMask) > 2359) {
            $(this).val("23:59");
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#txtTime").setMask('time').val('hh:mm');

})
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/9dgYN/1/

Comment: why can't I use setMask()? `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setMask'` Other jquery codes are working normally. Also, I don't see any reference to setMask on jquery.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute to create the placeholder text, then use jQuery to add support for browsers that do not support it, and remove it once the `input` element gains focus.

```
var timeTxt = $("#txtTime").setMask('time');
var placeholder = timeTxt.attr('placeholder');

timeTxt.val(placeholder).focus(function(){
    if(this.value === placeholder){
        this.value = '';
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if(!this.value){
        this.value = placeholder;
    }
});
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/9dgYN/2/. You should also consider using a script such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to add feature detection for the `placeholder` attribute.