# How do I guide a user's input in HTML using a format?

Tags: jquery, html

I understand the concept of the placeholder attribute, but I am trying to more strictly guide the user.  Once the user enters data in the input field with the placeholder text, it vanishes, and I would like it to persist.

I am trying to have the user input a timestamp in the form of HH:MM.  But I would like my input to first appear as `__:__`, where when a user enters a number, it replaces the `_` with that number. When they reach the `:`, it skips over it, and the semicolon can never be deleted.  I'm not exactly sure what phrase to google this scenario for, so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: “Input field mask” should do as a search term.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by CBroe, the input field mask will help in your situation.

You can consider using plugins/libraries like:

- http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
- https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

They can be really helpful.

Cheers! Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

Check out following links

[Input Time masking using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965366/input-time-mask-using-jquery)

[More advanced way](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

[Another one Jquery plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)